# php - adding data into json

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to know if the new data can be added to JSON before encoding it?

I am retrieving the data from MySQL database in the following way:

```
//fetch the data from the database
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $to_encode[] = $row;
}
```

which gives me this:

```
[
    {
        name: "aaa"
    },
    {
        name: "bbb"
    }
]
```

Then I encode it to JSON with:

```
$array1 =  json_encode($to_encode)
```

I wanted to know if I can add more data into the array before encoding it to make it like this?

```
[
    {
        name: "aaa"
        age: '5'
    },
    {
        name: "bbb"
        age: '5'
    }
]
```

or should I decode the encoded JSON, add the new values and then encode it back?

Comment: If you're retrieving all of the information from the database, it's more efficient to use a join statement so that the name and age appear in one row and to iterate through those results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can do like this:

```
//fetch the data from the database
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $to_encode[] = $row;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($to_encode); $i++) {
$to_encode[$i]['age'] = '14';
}

$array1 =  json_encode($to_encode);
print_r($array1);
```

Comment: the key 'name' and its value is retrieved from the database. I just want to add another key value pair to the same object with key being age for example

Comment: @HardikVasa, I have updated my answer. I don't know how you will make age dynamic. but i used hard-coded 14. It might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
$i=0;
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $to_encode[$i]["name"] = $row;
    $to_encode[$i]["age"] = 5;
    $i++;
}
$array1 =  json_encode($to_encode)
```

Comment: this does not work...it adds all the 'name' keys and its values and then adds one 'age' key value at the end

Comment: no disrespect but your accepted answer will take 2 loop which is time consuming. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can push an array to the $row variable, the idea is to build the array before you use json_encode

```
$to_encode = [];

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $age = array('age'=>5);
    array_push($to_encode,$row);
    array_push($to_encode,$age);
}

$array = json_encode($to_encode);
```